# Getting NSImage from CGImageRef

Tags: macos, core-graphics, nsimage, cgimageref

I am trying process an image in CoreGraphics and then return the processed image back to an `NSImage` for saving and displaying. I have ample resources on how to perform these functions in iOS but the helper methods seem to be missing in `NSImage`. In iOS the class method is `imageWithCGImage:`, how can you do this in Mac OS?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The matching method in NSImage is `initWithCGImage:size:`.

The second argument takes the image's size in points. The factor between the size in pixels (of the CGImage) and the size in points is the scale factor. So, for example, if you have a 100×100px CGImage, and pass a size of `(NSSize){ 50.0, 50.0 }`, the image will be 50 points in size, and double-resolution.

Usually you should just pass the size in pixels (from the CGImage) as the size in points. For handling multiple scale factors, it's better to use a single NSImage with multiple NSImageReps, like what you get from `-[NSWorkspace iconForFileType:]` for most types or from creating an NSImage from a typical .icns file.

Comment: NSZeroSize is shorthand for "same size as the CGImage".