# Convert CGImage to NSImage Swift

Tags: swift, nsimage, cgimage

I am trying to display a CGImage in a NSImageView box and I am having trouble converting the CGImage to a NSImage. How should I approach this situation ? Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/initWithCGImage:size: `init(CGImage cgImage: CGImage, size size: NSSize)`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098388/getting-nsimage-from-cgimageref ?

Comment: thank you very much! Apparently I ignored the proper initialization of the NSSize parameter when I tried the init... :D

Answer (score 6):

Partially based on Larme's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585589/convert-cgimage-to-nsimage-swift#comment64559504_38585589):

- for Swift, the NSImage initializer that takes a CGImage is [`init(cgImage:size:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519939-init) and a syntax example is:

  ```
  let myNsImage = NSImage(cgImage: myCgImage, size: .zero)
  ```

  `.zero` is a convenience for using the same size as the CGImage.
- for Objective-C, see [Getting NSImage from CGImageRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098388/getting-nsimage-from-cgimageref).

And as a simplified demonstration (`!` on purpose), this macOS Playground will visually render `nsImage` identically to the programmatically generated `cgImage`:

```
import AppKit
let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue
let s: UInt32 = 0xffbbbbbb, o: UInt32 = 0xff3d85e6, f: UInt32 = 0x00000000
let width = 12; let height = 15
var pixels = [
    f, f, f, f, f, f, f, o, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, o, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, o, f, f, f, f, f, f, o, f, f, f, f, o, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, o, f, f, f, f, o, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, o, f, f, f, o, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, o, f, f, f, o, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, o, o, f, f, o, f, f, o, o, f, f, f, f, f, o, o, f, f, f, f, f, o, o, o, o, f, f, f, f, s, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, o, o, f, s, s, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, s, s, f, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, f, s, s, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s,
]
var context: CGContext!
pixels.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { bufferPointer in
    context = CGContext(data: bufferPointer.baseAddress, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: width * 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo, releaseCallback: nil, releaseInfo: nil)
}
let cgImage = context.makeImage()!
let nsImage = NSImage(cgImage: cgImage, size: .zero)
_ = nsImage
```